Error: The provided keyfile does not define a valid redirect URI in nodejs
I want to use google drive api with nodejs.  I have deployed project on server and then I am getting this error:

redirect URI. There must be at least one redirect URI defined, and this sample
assumes it redirects to 'http://localhost:3000/oauth2callback'.
Please edit your keyfile, and add a 'redirect_uris' section.  For example:
"redirect_uris": [
"http://localhost:3000/oauth2callback"
]

I have already created register api and create credential on console and in credential file also redirect_uris is available.
I have make project on localhost that time redirect url is working because in redirect urls is http://localhost:3001/oauth now I have deployed at this time my redirect_uris https://domain-name/path now it shows error as i mention my credential file is as below:


redirect uris need to be https when hosted.  2. if its hosted i dont think you should be running localhost as your redirect uri.  3. redirect uri needs to be added in google developer console as well as valid.   Please edit your question and include [example]

